# convert JSON to a another JSON format with recursion

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

Please help me to create a recursive function to convert the JSON from given format to the JSON below. I'm a bit lost how to do it.
Thank you for help!
Below are the sample JSON format that I have and need to convert.

This is provided:

```
{
  "context": {
    "device":          {
      "localeCountryCode": "AX",
      "datetime":          "3047-09-29T07:09:52.498Z"
    },
    "currentLocation": {
      "country": "KM",
      "lon":     -78789486,
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
{
  "label":    "context",
  "children": [
    {
      "label":    "device",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "localeCountryCode"
        },
        {
          "label": "datetime"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label":    "currentLocation",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "country"
        },
        {
          "label": "lon"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what given format? We can't answer this without the format you have and the format you want.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the relevant information. Please include an example of the data you are working with.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the relevant information.

Comment: Still have no idea what you are actually asking? It seems more of a "Please write this for me" post.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just stared at it? Wrote some code which fails? Wrote some code you are not happy with, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the object is truthy and get the keys of the object. Then return for every key an object with the label and a children property with the result of the recursive call of the function.

```js
function transform(o) {
    if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(o).map(function (k) {
            var children = transform(o[k]);
            return children ? { label: k, children: children } : { label: k };
        });
    }
}

var object = { context: { device: { localeCountryCode: "AX", datetime: "3047-09-29T07:09:52.498Z" }, currentLocation: { country: "KM", lon: -78789486, } } },
    result = transform(object);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```